# Help in identifying our newest project

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

[image: unknown tandem bike]
Any help getting info on this bike would be great. Only tags/badges are a Japan stamp and a diamond with a 5 in the middle under the frame. Thought maybe a Japanese knockoff from Schwinn but the bars and brakes are different.

Comment: The one interesting thing is the fact that both chains are on the right side. Most tandems run the captain to stoker chain on the left. This could be due to the use of Ashtabula (one piece) cranks which points to low-end production. It might be difficult to find extensive information. It could be a one-off piece from a frame-builder who assembled two similar bikes.